# How to change colour of CubeGeometry with Three.js?

Tags: three.js

Note that I need to change it's colour *after* it has been created. I can create a new cube based on the original, but I would really rather not do that. In my use case there are many cubes with references all over the place and it would be a pain to update them all. Also, they will change their colour fairly often.

There must be a better way to do this?

```
var startColours  = [0x0000FF, 0x00FF00, 0xFF0000, 0x00FFFF, 0xFF00FF, 0xFFFF00];
var changeColours = [0x000000, 0x000000, 0x808080, 0x808080, 0xFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFF];
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( 
    { color: 0xFFFFFF, shading: THREE.FlatShading, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors });

var setColours = function(geometry, colours) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        geometry.faces[i].color.setHex(colours[i]);
    }
}

var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
setColours(geometry, startColours);
var cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cubeMesh);

// Try and change the colour after 2 seconds.
setTimeout("attempt2()", 2000);

function attempt1() {
    // Do the obvious.
    setColours(geometry, changeColours);
    // Doesn't work - no errors, but the cube just doesn't change colour.
}

function attempt2() {
    setColours(geometry, changeColours);

    scene.remove(cubeMesh);
    // Create a new mesh with a *clone* of the geometry and material of the original.
    var newCubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeMesh.geometry.clone(), cubeMesh.material);
    scene.add(newCubeMesh);
    // Does work - but having to create a completely new Mesh object is pants.
}
```

Comment: Most probably, you need to set material.needsUpdate = true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [MeshFaceMaterial](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshFaceMaterial).

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpe5g51k/2/)

```
function setColours() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    box.material.materials[i].color.setHex(changeColours[i]);
  }
}

var startMaterials = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
  startMaterials.push(new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: startColours[i]}));
}
var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(startMaterials);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 40, 20, 2, 2, 2);

box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(box);

setTimeout(setColours, 3000);
```